# What is LSN in the cd-info track list?

Tags: data-cd

When I run cd-info the track list looks like this:

```
CD-ROM Track List (1 - 1)
  #: MSF       LSN    Type   Green? Copy?
  1: 00:02:00  000000 data   false  no   
170: 68:17:27  307152 leadout (688 MB raw, 599 MB formatted)
```

What does LSN mean and what does it stand for?
I checked the man page and Google and found nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LSN is [the Logical Sector Number](https://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/libcdio.html#Sectors), similar to the Logical Block Address more commonly used on disks.